# writing a query to to generate two records from one record based on some condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have table with columns:

- flag1
- flag2
- flag1_column1
- flag1_column2
- flag1_column3
- flag2_column1
- flag2_column2
- flag2_column3

my requirement is:

- If both `flag1` and `flag2` have value true then in result I should get two records:

  1. `flag1, flag1_column1, flag1_column2, flag1_column3`
  2. `flag2, flag2_column1, flag2_column2, flag2_column3`

my second requirement:

If `flag1` is `null` or `0` then I should get only one record:

```
flag2 ,flag2_column1, flag2_column2, flag2_column3
```

my third requirement:

If `flag2` is `null` or `0` then I should get only one record:

```
flag1 , flag1_column1, flag1_column2, flag1_column3
```

Comment: what if they're both null/0?

Comment: it can not be null. so always be 0 or 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is query that returns desired result:

```
select flag1 as flag,
       flag1_column1 as c1, 
       flag1_column2 as c2, 
       flag1_column3 as c3 
from t where flag1=1
union
select flag2 as flag,
       flag2_column1 as c1, 
       flag2_column2 as c3, 
       flag2_column3 as c3 
from t where flag2=1
```